# jquery ui autocomplete special characters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I created a small jquery example with jquery UI autocomplete

```
$(function() {
    //autocomplete
    $(".selector").autocomplete({
        source: "getdata.php",
        minLength: 1

    });
})
```

`getdata.php`:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $return_arr = array();

    try {
        $connectionInfo = array('Database'=>'db','UID'=>'sa','PWD'=>'pw');
        $connection = sqlsrv_connect('db-server',$connectionInfo); 

        if($connection)
        {
            $result = sqlsrv_query( $connection, 'SELECT TOP 10 test FROM table WHERE test like ? ',array('%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));
            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
                $row = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
                $return_arr[] =  $row['test'];
            }
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }



    /* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
?>
```

---

and it works but the problem is that the data source is not Unicode so the strings don't show up correctly I don't know what kind of transformation to use.

If possible I would like to keep the same encoding as in database (Windows-1250) as this project might also insert stuff back from the website to the db

I tried just to dump the original strings but then I get values with special characters as null in json when the return array get's transformed

Answer (score 0):

You can encoder your data before display it in autocomplete

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I did try to baes64 ecode the strings before putting them into json but I don't know what event of the 'jquery .ui.autocomplete' to use to decode them back before they get displayed